# tns doctor saying that "abd from the Android SDK is not installed"

Tags: android, sdk, nativescript, tns

I'm having a bit of an issue setting up my local environment to work with Android SDK and Nativescript.

My path in `.bashrc` looks like:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/mkrul/.android"
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}/sdk/platform-tools/abd"
```

My sdk folder is located in `/home/mkrul/.android/sdk`

abd is located inside of `/home/mkrul/.android/platform-tools`

My `android-studio` folder was extracted to `/usr/local`

Been struggling with this for a few hours now trying different things and I'm still not getting the green light from `tns doctor`.  I am able to start up android studio and run an emulated device without any warnings from the program itself. I have also been sure to source my .bashrc file and logout/log in after each change.

Answer (score 0):

And of course, the issue was my path all along...  It *should* have been:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/mkrul/.android/sdk"
export PATH="${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/:${ANDROID_HOME}/platforms/"
```